# Unable to call the SharePoint Custom web service from another SharePoint Farm

Tags: 2007, web-services, asp.net

I have deployed a custom SharePoint Web service on Farm A. I am trying to access this Web service from a SharePoint timer job on Farm B. On Farm B, I am creating Class Library project, packaging it (wsp) and then deploying to GAC. The problem is I'm unable to access the Web Service using the following code. TodaysNewSVC is a service reference

```
      TodaysNewSVC.GetTodaysnewsfromInsite objGetNews = new    TodaysNewSVC.GetTodaysnewsfromInsite();
      objGetNews.PreAuthenticate = true;
      objGetNews.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
      objGetNews.Url = "http://insite-dev.portal/_vti_bin/todaysnews.asmx";
      DataTable dt2 = objGetNews.getNewsFromInsite(true, true);

//getNewsFromInsite is a WebMethod which returns the DataTable.
```

**Note**: Both farms use the same active directory authentication. I have also done the debugging for Timer Job and feature activation and they are working fine. The problem occurs during the call i.e. `getNewsFromInsite`

The asmx and wsdl files are accessible from Internet Explorer and also from Windows Console application. Here is the code which I use from console application:

```
GetTodaysnewsfromInsiteSoapClient objWSClient = new GetTodaysnewsfromInsiteSoapClient();
objWSClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
objWSClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
DataTable dt = objWSClient.getNewsFromInsite(true, true);
```

**Here is the error message:**

```
The request failed with the error message:
--
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="%2fPages%2fproblem-with-page.aspx%3fc%3d500">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Comment: what is the error that is thrown from getNewsFromInsite?

Comment: the above issue is occurring due to of authentication!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like the web service on Farm A is throwing some sort of internal error (based on the error message "problem-with-page.aspx?c=500")

Have you attached the debugger to the web service? Also, how is the redirect to the problem-with-page.aspx being implemented? This looks like a custom error handler.

Comment: Very Intelligent of you! I managed to step into the WS itself, which solved the issue. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Are both farms running on the same hardware? You may need to disable loopback check on your server to enable a web services call back into the same machine.

Comment: No, they are on different hardware. Although, I did add the Farm A's Web app and IP address into host file Located on Farm B.

Comment: can you run two farms on the same server? do you have an links that show how to do this?

Comment: Yes, through virtualization.

Comment: @SPDoctor, its an authentication issue!